# Custom list-style "bullet" or getting list number transparently

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple list

```
<ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ol>
```

I need to start each list with `Step X:`.  I can of course just manually write that out, but I would prefer if it were built automatically by the CSS.  Something like:

```
ol li:before {
    content: "Step $";
}
```

... where it can acquire the list position and insert it to `$`.  Ideally it would also appear like this:

---

#### Step X

Content for step.  No extra line break above this line

---

...but what I need more than anything else is "Step X" to have the correct content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Counters in CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters):

```
ol {
    counter-reset: step;
}

ol li:before {
    counter-increment: step;
    content: "Step " counter(step);
    /* You may need to add : and/or space, e.g. "Step " counter(step) ": "; */
}
```

Decent browser support (IE8+ and all other major browsers), and you can still style the `:before` pseudo-element (the Step X text) separately. No line break will be present unless you display as a block as `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements display inline by default.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a counter?

Like this?

```
Step 1 bla bla bla
Step 2 bla bla bla
```

If that's so...

```
<body>
    <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
body 
{
    counter-reset: stepx;
}
li:before
{
    counter-increment: stepx;
    content: "Step "counter(stepx);
}
```

**IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.**